# How to parse JSON data when data's depth is deep?

Tags: python, json, pandas, parsing

I have stucked with some JSON data.

I want to parse JSON data and create pandas dataframe.
So I use json_normalize function, but data's depth is deep so data is not normalized well.

My json file is like,

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "result": [
      {
        "@type": "raw.transaction",
        "utime": 1681201600,
        "data": "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",
        "transaction_id": {
          "@type": "internal.transactionId",
          "lt": "36748988000020",
          "hash": "njUKYhNMhYeK5PcW3VioddftTFCNTzlnKLtX5XblP00="
        },
        "fee": "8709000",
        "storage_fee": "0",
        "other_fee": "8709000",
        "in_msg": {
          "@type": "raw.message",
          "source": "EQA67Q0JdrsjkXiZwagjdVvBmxn506TO2uaAxLxKPmRIFmxT",
          "destination": "EQBVO1szAYJcLa-6JHeZdacFGpF1zwH8nnQ_XA1wHSp60f54",
          "value": "74414676",
          "fwd_fee": "6772719",
          "ihr_fee": "0",
          "created_lt": "36748988000019",
          "body_hash": "L96+jEdk+hOehHWSM91D47M5bsPc2V2NrUVHcjPLdps=",
          "msg_data": {
            "@type": "msg.dataRaw",
            "body": "te6cckEBAQEAVgAApxeNRRkAAAAAAAAAAELgXI4oAGIW42aAMEct63QRIGEDQ97Vab6uNHlPYL3/SJiUdh8lABmZK3d26YG9S7Fd1UlCKDU7SEtXZlrlan8IXcAFl/ZPAZ5FJZE=",
            "init_state": "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"
          },
          "message": "F41FGQAAAAAAAAAAQuBcjigAYhbjZoAwRy3rdBEgYQND3tVpvq40eU9gvf9ImJR2HyUAGZkrd3bp\\ngb1LsV3VSUIoNTtIS1dmWuVqfwhdwAWX9k8A\\n"
        },
        "out_msgs": [
          {
            "@type": "raw.message",
            "source": "EQBVO1szAYJcLa-6JHeZdacFGpF1zwH8nnQ_XA1wHSp60f54",
            "destination": "EQBmZK3d26YG9S7Fd1UlCKDU7SEtXZlrlan8IXcAFl_ZPLGq",
            "value": "63414676",
            "fwd_fee": "666672",
            "ihr_fee": "0",
            "created_lt": "36748988000021",
            "body_hash": "la37uGspaEdb70INRgaUtfLiBGlqXsrLMlKwhwvngQY=",
            "msg_data": {
              "@type": "msg.dataRaw",
              "body": "te6cckEBAQEADgAAGNUydtsAAAAAAAAAAPfBmNw=",
              "init_state": ""
            },
            "message": "1TJ22wAAAAAAAAAA\\n"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "@type": "raw.transaction",
        "utime": 1681201600,
        "data": "te6cckECHQEABcoAA7V1U7WzMBglwtr7okd5l1pwUakXXPAfyedD9cDXAdKnrRAAAhbEpgJw84dN+IeB31wPeHeTv+QYy+5rB5Lv/c0yCWKJdTDC3bugAAIWxJuE5DZDUZwAADRvVuwoAQIDAgHgBAUAgnJqm3RtKZZvhHfCRqGpYjJ3IJJ1rsRiC4b7lDXR8823tNhDClpxd40WRNwRdkUoZfzePStwvePsW15QHGvQI94GAhcEQkkAUOvSGG60KREbHAKxaAC0+oY1ZHY4kOLWT51Yu0PZOWRAf6LyBnGzvNh1V8gWSQAVTtbMwGCXC2vuiR3mXWnBRqRdc8B/J50P1wNcB0qetFAFDr0gBs6GMgAAQtiUwE4cyGozgeAGBwEB3xoCATQJCAClF41FGQAAAAAAAAAAMWIp2AASbbsD22HP0Mzs0Fuwhk2QX+AqBPsB3Wb1ldmTYhwXZwAZmSt3dumBvUuxXdVJQig1O0hLV2Za5Wp/CF3ABZf2TwEBhwgAzMlbu7dMDepdiu6qShFBqdpCWrsy1ytT+ELuACy/snkAF/r5ihH3HKWiX83CMesuStMUBkkJf5ux35fH/3TY5o9gCQEU/wD0pBP0vPLICwoCAWILDAICzA0OABug9gXaiaH0AfSB9IGoYQIB1A8QAgEgERIAtwgxwCSXwTgAdDTAwFxsJUTXwPwDOD6QPpAMfoAMXHXIfoAMfoAMALTHyGCEA+KfqW6lTE0WfAJ4CGCEBeNRRm6ljFERAPwCuA1ghBZXwe8upNZ8AvgXwSED/LwgABE+kQwwADy4U2ACASATFACB1AEGuQ9qJofQB9IH0gahgCaY+QwQgLxqKM3QFBCD3uy+9dCVj5cWLpn5j9ABgJ0CgR5CgCfQEsZ4sA54tmZPaqQB8VA9M/+gD6QCHwAe1E0PoA+kD6QNQwUTahUirHBfLiwSjC//LiwlQ0QnBUIBNUFAPIUAT6AljPFgHPFszJIsjLARL0APQAywDJIPkAcHTIywLKB8v/ydAE+kD0BDH6ACDXScIA8uLEd4AYyMsFUAjPFnD6AhfLaxPMgVAgEgFhcAnoIQF41FGcjLHxnLP1AH+gIizxZQBs8WJfoCUAPPFslQBcwjkXKRceJQCKgToIIJycOAoBS88uLFBMmAQPsAECPIUAT6AljPFgHPFszJ7VQC9ztRND6APpA+kDUMAjTP/oAUVGgBfpA+kBTW8cFVHNtcFQgE1QUA8hQBPoCWM8WAc8WzMkiyMsBEvQA9ADLAMn5AHB0yMsCygfL/8nQUA3HBRyx8uLDCvoAUaihggiYloBmtgihggiYloCgGKEnlxBJEDg3XwTjDSXXCwGAYGQDfO1E0PoA+kD6QNQwB9M/+gD6QPQEMFFioVJaxwXy4sEowv/y4sIGggkxLQCgF7zy4sOCEHvdl97Iyx/LP1AF+gIhzxZQA88W9ADJcYAYyMsFJM8WcPoCy2rMyYBA+wBAE8hQBPoCWM8WAc8WzMntVIABwUnmgGKGCEHNi0JzIyx9SMMs/WPoCUAfPFlAHzxbJcYAQyMsFJM8WUAb6AhXLahTMyXH7ABAkECMAfMMAI8IAsI4hghDVMnbbcIAQyMsFUAjPFlAE+gIWy2oSyx8Syz/JcvsAkzVsIeIDyFAE+gJYzxYBzxbMye1UAMdIAKp2tmYDBLhbX3RI7zLrTgo1IuueA/k86H64GuA6VPWjABmZK3d26YG9S7Fd1UlCKDU7SEtXZlrlan8IXcAFl/ZPDm9aIAYUWGAAAELYlMBOIMhqM4BqmTttgAAAAAAAAABAAJxDw6lLdAAAAAAAAAAAnwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAb8mHoSBMFFhAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAC93ZguJGRj33PiZmk3H5JUsfr7Hkae5+bcUyOYsi+ZuJAUBjMyUU1ZA==",
        "transaction_id": {
          "@type": "internal.transactionId",
          "lt": "36748988000015",
          "hash": "8tJ1YrCD/675o1T9xQqbK5+a6S96pZ0Jg5XhSj1OO08="
        },
        "fee": "8709009",
        "storage_fee": "9",
        "other_fee": "8709000",
        "in_msg": {
          "@type": "raw.message",
          "source": "EQBafUMasjscSHFrJ86sXaHsnLIgP9F5AzjZ3mw6q-QLJNdK",
          "destination": "EQBVO1szAYJcLa-6JHeZdacFGpF1zwH8nnQ_XA1wHSp60f54",
          "value": "21213000",
          "fwd_fee": "6767385",
          "ihr_fee": "0",
          "created_lt": "36748988000014",
          "body_hash": "DrN7NHFbD+oBNdQ1HbYbuI4WiGgEA6i8MlJEGAl9oZc=",
          "msg_data": {
            "@type": "msg.dataRaw",
            "body": "te6cckEBAQEAVQAApReNRRkAAAAAAAAAADFiKdgAEm27A9thz9DM7NBbsIZNkF/gKgT7Ad1m9ZXZk2IcF2cAGZkrd3bpgb1LsV3VSUIoNTtIS1dmWuVqfwhdwAWX9k8BICtpNg==",
            "init_state": "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"
          },
          "message": "F41FGQAAAAAAAAAAMWIp2AASbbsD22HP0Mzs0Fuwhk2QX+AqBPsB3Wb1ldmTYhwXZwAZmSt3dumB\\nvUuxXdVJQig1O0hLV2Za5Wp/CF3ABZf2TwA=\\n"
        },
        "out_msgs": [
          {
            "@type": "raw.message",
            "source": "EQBVO1szAYJcLa-6JHeZdacFGpF1zwH8nnQ_XA1wHSp60f54",
            "destination": "EQBmZK3d26YG9S7Fd1UlCKDU7SEtXZlrlan8IXcAFl_ZPLGq",
            "value": "10213000",
            "fwd_fee": "666672",
            "ihr_fee": "0",
            "created_lt": "36748988000016",
            "body_hash": "la37uGspaEdb70INRgaUtfLiBGlqXsrLMlKwhwvngQY=",
            "msg_data": {
              "@type": "msg.dataRaw",
              "body": "te6cckEBAQEADgAAGNUydtsAAAAAAAAAAPfBmNw=",
              "init_state": ""
            },
            "message": "1TJ22wAAAAAAAAAA\\n"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

I want to only get data, "utime", "in_msg"'s sub data, "out_msgs"'s sub data. Then I want to save dataframe.

Comment: Since you provide a small chunk of your data, you have to ensure the JSON is valid (which is not the case here).

Comment: Because you only provided a sample of the JSON, it had no closing `]`, `}` chars making it "invalid", I added those in. It would also help if you added an example of the output dataframe you need. (It probably makes sense to truncate the `body` and `init_state` values as they just clutter things due to their length)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following (with `data.json` the JSON-file):

```py
# Get records
data = pd.read_json("data.json")["result"].to_list()

# Build a `utime` & `in_msg` dataframe
df1 = pd.json_normalize(data)
drop_cols = [c for c in df1.columns if c != "utime" and not c.startswith("in_msg.")]
df1 = df1.drop(columns=drop_cols)

# Build a `out_msgs` dataframe
df2 = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path="out_msgs")
df2.columns = [f"out_msgs.{c}" for c in df2.columns]

# Concatenate both
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Result for the sample with shortened data:

```
        utime in_msg.@type in_msg.source in_msg.destination in_msg.value  \
0  1681201600  raw.message     EQA67Q0Jd            EQBVO1s     74414676   
1  1681201600  raw.message      EQBafUMa            EQBVO1s     21213000   

  in_msg.fwd_fee in_msg.ihr_fee in_msg.created_lt in_msg.body_hash  \
0        6772719              0    36748988000019          L96+jEd   
1        6767385              0    36748988000014       DrN7NHFbD+   

  in_msg.msg_data.@type in_msg.msg_data.body in_msg.msg_data.init_state  \
0           msg.dataRaw        te6cckEBAQEAV                  te6cckECE   
1           msg.dataRaw          te6cckEBAQE                  te6cckECE   

  in_msg.message out_msgs.@type out_msgs.source out_msgs.destination  \
0        F41FGQA    raw.message          EQBVO1              EQBmZK3   
1       F41FGQAA    raw.message         EQBVO1s                EQBmZ   

  out_msgs.value out_msgs.fwd_fee out_msgs.ihr_fee out_msgs.created_lt  \
0       63414676           666672                0      36748988000021   
1       10213000           666672                0      36748988000016   

  out_msgs.body_hash out_msgs.message out_msgs.msg_data.@type  \
0           la37uGsp          1TJ22wA             msg.dataRaw   
1           la37uGsp       1TJ22wAAAA             msg.dataRaw   

  out_msgs.msg_data.body out_msgs.msg_data.init_state  
0               te6cckEB                               
1            te6cckEBAQE
```